# MultiMap / Reduce Index field issue

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I have a MultiMap/Reduce index which is working great, however I now want to query on one of the fields...but the field is within a child object...

```
ReduceResult
 - Name
 - Description
 - GenreObject
    - Name
    - Code
```

I have tried various options but I still get the error below:

```
Index(x => x.Genre.Code, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
Store(x => x.Genre.Code, FieldStorage.Yes);
```

or
    Index(x => x.Genre, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    Store(x => x.Genre, FieldStorage.Yes);

I can see in the management console that it has the field 'Code' indexed, however it seems to be looking for Genre_Code.

---

```
Url: "/indexes/AudioWithCounters?query=Genre_Code%253Ahouse&start=0&pageSize=25&aggregation=None&sort=-WeeksComments"

System.ArgumentException: The field 'Genre_Code' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
```

---

I tried to change the Indexed field name to 'Genre_Code' manually in the management console, but it doesn't seem to save.

I know I can probably flatter my Genre object but id rather not if I can get away with it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE - Full Index:**

```
namespace HM.Web.Infrastructure.Indexes
{
    public class AudioWithCounters : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<AudioWithCounters.AudioViewModel>
    {
        public class AudioViewModel
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string ArtistName { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Identifier { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
            public Genre Genre { get; set; } 
            public DateTimeOffset? DateAdded { get; set; }
            public UserImage Image { get; set; }
            public int TotalComments { get; set; }
            public int TotalDownloads { get; set; }
            public int TotalPlays { get; set; }
            public int TotalLikes { get; set; }
            public int TotalFavourites { get; set; }
            public int WeeksComments { get; set; }
            public int WeeksDownloads { get; set; }
            public int WeeksPlays { get; set; }
            public int WeeksLikes { get; set; }
            public int WeeksFavourites { get; set; }
        }

        public AudioWithCounters()
        {
            AddMap<Audio>(audios => from audio in audios
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = audio.Id,
                                        ArtistName = audio.ArtistName,
                                        Name = audio.Name,
                                        Identifier = audio.Identifier,
                                        Description = audio.Description,
                                        Tags = audio.Tags,
                                        Genre = audio.Genre,
                                        DateAdded = audio.DateAdded,
                                        Image = audio.Image,
                                        TotalDownloads = 0,
                                        TotalComments = audio.CommentsCount,
                                        TotalPlays = 0,
                                        TotalLikes = 0,
                                        TotalFavourites = 0,
                                        WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                        WeeksPlays = 0,
                                        WeeksComments = 0,
                                        WeeksLikes = 0,
                                        WeeksFavourites = 0
                                    });

            AddMap<AudioComments>(comments => from audioComment in comments
                                              from comment in audioComment.Comments
                                              where comment.CreatedAt >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = audioComment.Audio.Id,
                                        ArtistName = (string)null,
                                        Name = (string)null,
                                        Identifier = (string)null,
                                        Description = (string)null,
                                        Tags = (object)null,
                                        Genre = (object)null,
                                        DateAdded = (object)null,
                                        Image = (object)null,
                                        TotalDownloads = 0,
                                        TotalComments = 0,
                                        TotalPlays = 0,
                                        TotalLikes = 0,
                                        TotalFavourites = 0,
                                        WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                        WeeksPlays = 0,
                                        WeeksComments = 1,
                                        WeeksLikes = 0,
                                        WeeksFavourites = 0
                                    });


            AddMap<AudioCounter>(counters => from counter in counters
                                             where counter.Type == Core.Enums.Audio.AudioCounterType.Download
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = counter.AudioId,
                                        ArtistName = (string)null,
                                        Name = (string)null,
                                        Identifier = (string)null,
                                        Description = (string)null,
                                        Tags = (object)null,
                                        Genre = (object)null,
                                        DateAdded = (object)null,
                                        Image = (object)null,
                                        TotalDownloads = 1,
                                        TotalComments = 0,
                                        TotalPlays = 0,
                                        TotalLikes = 0,
                                        TotalFavourites = 0,
                                        WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                        WeeksPlays = 0,
                                        WeeksComments = 0,
                                        WeeksLikes = 0,
                                        WeeksFavourites = 0
                                    });

            AddMap<AudioCounter>(counters => from counter in counters
                                             where counter.Type == Core.Enums.Audio.AudioCounterType.Play
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Id = counter.AudioId,
                                                 ArtistName = (string)null,
                                                 Name = (string)null,
                                                 Identifier = (string)null,
                                                 Description = (string)null,
                                                 Tags = (object)null,
                                                 Genre = (object)null,
                                                 DateAdded = (object)null,
                                                 Image = (object)null,
                                                 TotalDownloads = 0,
                                                 TotalPlays = 1,
                                                 TotalComments = 0,
                                                 TotalLikes = 0,
                                                 TotalFavourites = 0,
                                                 WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                                 WeeksPlays = 0,
                                                 WeeksComments = 0,
                                                 WeeksLikes = 0,
                                                 WeeksFavourites = 0
                                             });

            AddMap<AudioCounter>(counters => from counter in counters
                                             where counter.Type == Core.Enums.Audio.AudioCounterType.Download
                                             where counter.DateTime >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Id = counter.AudioId,
                                                 ArtistName = (string)null,
                                                 Name = (string)null,
                                                 Identifier = (string)null,
                                                 Description = (string)null,
                                                 Tags = (object)null,
                                                 Genre = (object)null,
                                                 DateAdded = (object)null,
                                                 Image = (object)null,
                                                 TotalDownloads = 0,
                                                 TotalPlays = 0,
                                                 TotalComments = 0,
                                                 TotalLikes = 0,
                                                 TotalFavourites = 0,
                                                 WeeksDownloads = 1,
                                                 WeeksPlays = 0,
                                                 WeeksComments = 0,
                                                 WeeksLikes = 0,
                                                 WeeksFavourites = 0
                                             });

            AddMap<Like>(likes => from like in likes
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Id = like.AudioId,
                                                 ArtistName = (string)null,
                                                 Name = (string)null,
                                                 Identifier = (string)null,
                                                 Description = (string)null,
                                                 Tags = (object)null,
                                                 Genre = (object)null,
                                                 DateAdded = (object)null,
                                                 Image = (object)null,
                                                 TotalDownloads = 0,
                                                 TotalPlays = 0,
                                                 TotalComments = 0,
                                                 TotalLikes = 1,
                                                 TotalFavourites = 0,
                                                 WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                                 WeeksPlays = 0,
                                                 WeeksComments = 0,
                                                 WeeksLikes = 0,
                                                 WeeksFavourites = 0
                                             });

            AddMap<Favourite>(favs => from fav in favs
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Id = fav.AudioId,
                                      ArtistName = (string)null,
                                      Name = (string)null,
                                      Identifier = (string)null,
                                      Description = (string)null,
                                      Tags = (object)null,
                                      Genre = (object)null,
                                      DateAdded = (object)null,
                                      Image = (object)null,
                                      TotalDownloads = 0,
                                      TotalPlays = 0,
                                      TotalComments = 0,
                                      TotalLikes = 0,
                                      TotalFavourites = 1,
                                      WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                      WeeksPlays = 0,
                                      WeeksComments = 0,
                                      WeeksLikes = 0,
                                      WeeksFavourites = 0
                                  });

            AddMap<AudioCounter>(counters => from counter in counters
                                             where counter.Type == Core.Enums.Audio.AudioCounterType.Play
                                             where counter.DateTime >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Id = counter.AudioId,
                                                 ArtistName = (string)null,
                                                 Name = (string)null,
                                                 Identifier = (string)null,
                                                 Description = (string)null,
                                                 Tags = (object)null,
                                                 Genre = (object)null,
                                                 DateAdded = (object)null,
                                                 Image = (object)null,
                                                 TotalDownloads = 0,
                                                 TotalPlays = 0,
                                                 TotalComments = 0,
                                                 TotalLikes = 0,
                                                 TotalFavourites = 0,
                                                 WeeksDownloads = 1,
                                                 WeeksPlays = 0,
                                                 WeeksComments = 0,
                                                 WeeksLikes = 0,
                                                 WeeksFavourites = 0
                                             });

            AddMap<Like>(likes => from like in likes
                                  where like.DateCreated >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Id = like.AudioId,
                                      ArtistName = (string)null,
                                      Name = (string)null,
                                      Identifier = (string)null,
                                      Description = (string)null,
                                      Tags = (object)null,
                                      Genre = (object)null,
                                      DateAdded = (object)null,
                                      Image = (object)null,
                                      TotalDownloads = 0,
                                      TotalPlays = 0,
                                      TotalComments = 0,
                                      TotalLikes = 0,
                                      TotalFavourites = 0,
                                      WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                      WeeksPlays = 0,
                                      WeeksComments = 0,
                                      WeeksLikes = 1,
                                      WeeksFavourites = 0
                                  });

            AddMap<Favourite>(favs => from fav in favs
                                      where fav.DateCreated >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          Id = fav.AudioId,
                                          ArtistName = (string)null,
                                          Name = (string)null,
                                          Identifier = (string)null,
                                          Description = (string)null,
                                          Tags = (object)null,
                                          Genre = (object)null,
                                          DateAdded = (object)null,
                                          Image = (object)null,
                                          TotalDownloads = 0,
                                          TotalPlays = 0,
                                          TotalComments = 0,
                                          TotalLikes = 0,
                                          TotalFavourites = 0,
                                          WeeksDownloads = 0,
                                          WeeksPlays = 0,
                                          WeeksComments = 0,
                                          WeeksLikes = 0,
                                          WeeksFavourites = 1
                                      });

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.Id
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = g.Key,
                                        ArtistName = g.Select(x => x.ArtistName).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Identifier = g.Select(x => x.Identifier).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Description = g.Select(x => x.Description).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Tags = g.Select(x => x.Tags).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Genre = g.Select(x => x.Genre).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        DateAdded = g.Select(x => x.DateAdded).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Image = g.Select(x => x.Image).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        TotalDownloads = g.Sum(x => x.TotalDownloads),
                                        TotalPlays = g.Sum(x => x.TotalPlays),
                                        TotalComments = g.Sum(x => x.TotalComments),
                                        TotalLikes = g.Sum(x => x.TotalLikes),
                                        TotalFavourites = g.Sum(x => x.TotalFavourites),
                                        WeeksComments = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksComments),
                                        WeeksDownloads = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksDownloads),
                                        WeeksPlays = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksPlays),
                                        WeeksLikes = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksLikes),
                                        WeeksFavourites = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksFavourites)
                                    };

            Index(x => x.Genre.Code, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            Store(x => x.Genre.Code, FieldStorage.Yes);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you update the question so that it includes the index you are using, without that it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: updated with the full index code

Comment: Erm, that seems a really complicate index, also you have multiple AddMap<T> clauses for the same type which is a bit wierd. This might be better discussed on the RavenDB mailing list. Can you post there with a description of you docs and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I posted in the group but it's awaiting approval...another question related to this index was posted on SO, and someone said this is the recommended approach (maybe apart from the weekly counters).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is because the Genre.Code field isn't index. The output of a Map/Reduce index is the Reduce statement, which doesn't contain a Genre.Code field.

```
 Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.Id
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = g.Key,
                                        ArtistName = g.Select(x => x.ArtistName).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Identifier = g.Select(x => x.Identifier).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Description = g.Select(x => x.Description).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Tags = g.Select(x => x.Tags).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Genre = g.Select(x => x.Genre).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        DateAdded = g.Select(x => x.DateAdded).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Image = g.Select(x => x.Image).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        TotalDownloads = g.Sum(x => x.TotalDownloads),
                                        TotalPlays = g.Sum(x => x.TotalPlays),
                                        TotalComments = g.Sum(x => x.TotalComments),
                                        TotalLikes = g.Sum(x => x.TotalLikes),
                                        TotalFavourites = g.Sum(x => x.TotalFavourites),
                                        WeeksComments = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksComments),
                                        WeeksDownloads = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksDownloads),
                                        WeeksPlays = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksPlays),
                                        WeeksLikes = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksLikes),
                                        WeeksFavourites = g.Sum(x => x.WeeksFavourites)
                                    };
```

Merely setting the field to `Stored` doesnt solve that.

**But** the bigger question is why are you writing an index like this, see my comment above.